# link rewriting and deleting old links

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

i'm making this website and i've cleaned up my urls. The only thing i can't find on the web is how to delete the old ones so there is only 1 link to each page.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.eu/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^secured/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^login/$ paginas/login.php 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?taal=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?taal=$1&pagina=$2

ErrorDocument 404 /paginas/error404.php
```

So how can i make the index.php?taal=1&pagina=2 type of links to be unavailable so people can only use domain.eu/1/2/ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to exclude those urls? If the shorter version is better and users are redirected to them anyways, they will start using the short ones. In my eyes, it is bad usability to make the "old" urls stop working. A 301 redirect is a good solution for your problem!

Comment: Because they say that google doesn't like websites who have multiple urls to the same page. And how does the 301 works because if I put [R=301] after my rewrite rule it deletes the clean url and links to the old url. The old urls still working but it doesn't redirect them to the new ones. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: If you do not use those "old" urls somewhere, it does not matter for google. Duplicate content is only an issue if you link to the content with 2 different link. If you only use your new links, no problem. You could additionaly redirect users with the old urls to the new ones using a [301,L] and then rewrite the clean urls to the parameter version WITHOUT redirecting the user.